# How to use multiple navigation buttons for one slider using swiperjs in react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm using **swiprejs** and i have a slider, it is an **"EffectCards"** slider and inside each card i have two buttons, one for nextSlide and one for prevSlide, and i don't know how to make them work.
I know how to make custom naviagtion button for a slider, but i want to have **multiple** of them with the same job, because each card **has it's own** nextSlide and prevSilde button and they have to **work exactly the same**.

Could somebody please tell me, how can i make something like this?

(Having **two** nextSilde buttons for **one** slider for example)

Here is the code of the slider:

```
<Swiper
  navigation={{
    prevEl: navigationPrevRef.current,
    nextEl: navigationNextRef.current,
  }}
  onBeforeInit={(swiper) => {
   swiper.params.navigation.prevEl = navigationPrevRef.current;
   swiper.params.navigation.nextEl = navigationNextRef.current;
  }}
  effect={"cards"}
  grabCursor={true}
  loop={false}
  slidesPerGroupSkip={1}
  modules={[EffectCards, Navigation]}
  className="mySwiper"
>
  (item) => (
    <SwiperSlide key={item.id}>
      <BenefitItem
        item={item}
        onNextSlide={handleNextSlide}
        onPrevSlide={handlePrevSlide}
        navigationNextRef={navigationNextRef}
        navigationPrevRef={navigationPrevRef}
      />
    </SwiperSlide>
  )
</SwiperSlider>
```

And here are the buttons (they are inside the "BenefitItem" component):

```
<NavigationButton ref={navigationNextRef}>
  <LuArrowRight />
</NavigationButton>

<NavigationButton ref={navigationPrevRef}>
  <LuArrowLeft />
</NavigationButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save instance of swiper inside state and use it in on click of buttons.based on the example below, you can make as many buttons as you want

```html
    import SwiperClass from 'swiper';
    import { useState } from 'react';

    const CustomSlide=()=>{
      const [swiperState, setSwiperState] = useState<SwiperClass>();
     
      const handleNext = () => {
            swiperState?.slideNext();
        };
      const handlePrevious = () => {
            swiperState?.slidePrev();
      };
      return(
        <>
          <Swiper
             onSwiper={(swiper) => setSwiperState(swiper)}
             ...
          />
          <NavigationButton onClick={handlePrevious} >
            <LuArrowRight />
          </NavigationButton>

          <NavigationButton onClick={handleNext}>
            <LuArrowLeft />
          </NavigationButton>
        </>
      )
    }
```